# Ejecución BeanShell

Tags: java, string, compilador

estoy intentando ejecutar un assertEquals desde Java, este se encuentra contenido en un String, sería de la forma : `assertEquals(requestBean.getStatus(),200);`.

Para hacerlo uso `Interpreter` de BeanShell que es un compilador de Strings, el problema se da en que no ejecuta métodos de variables declaradas en la clase como tal, se tienen que declarar para el `Interpreter`, por ejemplo para ejecutar `requestBean.getStatus()` tuve que declarar una variable antes y asignarle el var de `requestBean` para que pudiese acceder a sus métodos.

```
Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
interpreter.set("requestBean", requestBean);
```

Entonces cuando intento ejecutar el assert surje el problema porque no puedo crear una variable assertEquals para trabajar con ella y al intentar compilar el código completo obtengo:

```
Sourced file: inline evaluation of: assertEquals(requestBean.getStatus(),200);
'' : Command not found: assertEquals( int, int ) : at Line: 1 : in file: 
inline evaluation of: assertEquals(requestBean.getStatus(),200);'' : assertEquals ( requestBean .getStatus ( ) , 200 ) 

at bsh.Name.invokeLocalMethod(Name.java:952)
at bsh.Name.invokeMethod(Name.java:804)
at bsh.BSHMethodInvocation.eval(BSHMethodInvocation.java:75)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:102)
at bsh.BSHPrimaryExpression.eval(BSHPrimaryExpression.java:47)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:645)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:739)
at bsh.Interpreter.eval(Interpreter.java:728)
at es.eurohelp.ldts.LodTest.executeJunit(LodTest.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Mi código:

```
@Test
public final void executeJunit() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, EvalError {

    String pTestName = "GETResourceRDFXML200";
    System.err.println(pTestName);
    LinkedDataRequestBean requestBean = xmlUtils.getXMLData2(pTestName);
    HttpManager.getInstance().doRequest(requestBean);
    Map<String, String> parameters = xmlUtils.getParameters(pTestName);
    Interpreter interpreter = new Interpreter();
    interpreter.set("requestBean", requestBean);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> conditionsToTest = xmlUtils.getTestConditionsToTest(pTestName);
    if (!parameters.isEmpty()) {
        requestBean.setParameters(parameters);
    }
    // En primer lugar ira el tipo de prueba, en segundo el objeto de
    // prueba, en tercero el modo de comparacion, y en cuarto el valor
    for (int i = 0; i < conditionsToTest.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < conditionsToTest.get(i).size(); j++) {

            if (conditionsToTest.get(0).get(j).contains("Equals")) {
                System.out.println("equals");
                String query = conditionsToTest.get(0).get(j) + "(" + conditionsToTest.get(1).get(j) + ","
                        + conditionsToTest.get(3).get(j) + ");";
                System.err.println(query);
                interpreter.eval(query);
            } else {// aqui si equals
                String query = conditionsToTest.get(0).get(j) + "(" + conditionsToTest.get(1).get(j)
                        + conditionsToTest.get(2).get(j) + "," + conditionsToTest.get(3).get(j) + ");";
                System.err.println(query);
                interpreter.eval(query);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Si tuvieseis alguna idea...

Gracias por vuestra atención.

Un saludo

Comment: supongo que has puesto 0 en lugar de i dentro del bucle cuando intentabas ver qué sucedía. No es que afecte al error, pero que no se te olvide luego ese detalle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que veo es que no has importado el método que quieres usar. BeanShell también admite sentencias `import java.util...` para poder hacer uso de las clases que necesites.

Prueba añadir algo como antes de ejecutar el método:

```
interpreter.eval("import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;");
```

O si los import static dan problemas, puedes probar con

```
interpreter.eval("import org.junit.Assert;");
```

y luego llamar al método usando `Assert.assertEquals(...)`

Comment: I tried it also and I get this error : In file: inline evaluation of: ``import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;'' Encountered "static" at line 1, column 8.

 at bsh.Parser.generateParseException(Parser.java:6068)
 at bsh.Parser.jj_consume_token(Parser.java:5939)
 at bsh.Parser.ImportDeclaration(Parser.java:464)
 at bsh.Parser.BlockStatement(Parser.java:2787)
 at bsh.Parser.Line(Parser.java:147)
..................................

Comment: Quizá tiene problemas con la importación "estática"... te añado otra opción

Comment: Con eso lo solucione, gracias!